# ros gazebo+rviz simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I am trying to launch huskyA200_gazebo map_office.launch..
I am getting the following error. Please help what ia have to chande in this header file  ****/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:****

roslaunch huskyA200_gazebo map_office.launch
... logging to /home/shakimca/.ros/log/677b8c94-9a60-11e1-b0b1-386077f24ea0/roslaunch-Adept7-8482.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Adept7:55956/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /rosversion
- /rosdistro

NODES
/
gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [8500]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 0.10.0

Part of the Player/Stage Project [http://playerstage.sourceforge.net].
Copyright (C) 2003 Nate Koenig, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the GNU General Public License.

Param [quickStepPreconIters] is deprecated: [replace quickStepPreconIters with stepPreconIters]
Param [quickStep] is deprecated: [replace quickStep with stepType]
Param [quickStepIters] is deprecated: [replace quickStepIters with stepIters]
Param [quickStepW] is deprecated: [replace quickStepW with stepW]
ScopedName[gplane]
ScopedName[willow_map]
ScopedName[point_white]
gazebo: /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.2**/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:252: void Ogre::AxisAlignedBox::setExtents(const Ogre::Vector3&, const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `(min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z <= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' failed.**
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 8500, exit code -6].
log files: /home/shakimca/.ros/log/677b8c94-9a60-11e1-b0b1-386077f24ea0/gazebo-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33670/ros-gazebo+rviz-simulation/) by [SHAKIMCA](https://answers.ros.org/users/2068/shakimca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-10**:
What graphics card are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at the answer to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/10986/model-of-katana-arm-jumps-around-violently-in) question. It might help you solve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0